# Changing form input to read only when elements reproduced

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So I am pretty clueless when it comes to jQuery and just inherited someone else's code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a form that is populated from a query as they add students to the form. They can have any number of students added to the form. Below is the html:

```
<table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <label class="control-label" >Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="" class="required" style="width: 290px">
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <label class="control-label" >Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email[]" value="" class="required">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <label class="control-label" >Address</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address1[]" value="" class="required" style="width: 290px">
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <label class="control-label" >Address 2 <small>(optional)</small></label>
                    <input type="text" name="address2[]" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">
                    <label class="control-label" >City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city[]" value="" style="width:120px;" class="required">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label class="control-label" >State/Providence</label>
                    <input type="text" name="st_prov[]" value="" style="width:120px;" class="required">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label class="control-label" >Postal Code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="zip_pc[]" value="" style="width:60px;" class="required">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label class="control-label" >Country</label>
                    <input type="text" name="country[]" value="" class="required">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
```

Here is the jQuery function that I've been trying to modify:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var addStudent = function(data){
        var studentEl = $($('.student').get(0)).clone()
        studentEl.find('input').each(function(){
            var field = $(this).attr('name').replace('[]','')
            if ($(this).attr("name").val == 'name'){
                $(this).prop("readonly", true);
            }
            $(this).val(data[field] || '')
        })
        if(data.client_no!=''){
            studentEl.find('.will_update').text("Will update student information for "+data.name+'')
        }
        $($('.student').last()).after(studentEl)
    }
})
```

The function creates an additional set of fields for each student populated by the database for the form to process.

I'm looking to modify the specific field for "name" to be readonly (can view but not modify but yet still submit). I've tried many other iterations but cannot get the field name in the if clause to make only that field read only.

Any help provided would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of getting an attribute via jQuery is just : `$(this).attr("name")`

Also instead of using:

```
var field = $(this).attr('name').replace('[]','')
            if ($(this).attr("name").val == 'name'){
                $(this).prop("readonly", true);
            }
```

Use the variable `field` that you already created:

```
var field = $(this).attr('name').replace('[]','')
            if (field  == 'name'){
                $(this).prop("readonly", true);
            }
```

See snippet below :

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var addStudent = function(data) {
    var studentEl = $($('.student').get(0)).clone()
    studentEl.find('input').each(function() {
      var field = $(this).attr('name').replace('[]', '')
      if (field == 'name') {
        $(this).prop("readonly", true);
      }
      $(this).val(data[field] || '')
    })
    if (data.client_no != '') {
      studentEl.find('.will_update').text("Will update student information for " + data.name + '')
    }
    $($('.student').last()).after(studentEl)
  }

  $('button').click(function() {
    addStudent({
      client_no: 1,
      name: "Ralph John "
    })
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%" class="student">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <label class="control-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name[]" value="" class="required" style="width: 290px">
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <label class="control-label">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email[]" value="" class="required">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <label class="control-label">Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="address1[]" value="" class="required" style="width: 290px">
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <label class="control-label">Address 2 <small>(optional)</small>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="address2[]" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">
      <label class="control-label">City</label>
      <input type="text" name="city[]" value="" style="width:120px;" class="required">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="control-label">State/Providence</label>
      <input type="text" name="st_prov[]" value="" style="width:120px;" class="required">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="control-label">Postal Code</label>
      <input type="text" name="zip_pc[]" value="" style="width:60px;" class="required">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="control-label">Country</label>
      <input type="text" name="country[]" value="" class="required">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button>Add Student</button>
```

Comment: I spoke too soon. It works great for the initial adding of student information, but all subsequent name fields are locked in readonly and they cannot add a second or third student to form. Thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: when i run my snippet above, i can add more than 1 form.. and its not readonly.. do you have other additional codes aside from the original question?

Comment: Here is the remainder of the code:
        
    $('#addStudent').click(function(){
        var newStudentId = $('#student').val()
        
        if(newStudentId==""){
            addStudent({})
        }else{
            $.getJSON('<?=url_for('trainer','student')?>',{'client_no': newStudentId}, function(data){
                addStudent(data)
            })
        }
        $('#student').prop('selectedIndex',0);

        return false;
    })

Comment: $('.delete').live('click',function(evt){
        if($('.student').size()==1){
            return false
        }
        evt.preventDefault()
        $(this).closest('.student').remove()
        return false
    })
    
    $('#mainForm').submit(function(){
        var filledIn = function(el){ return $(el).val().length >= 2 }
        var good = _.all($('.required'), filledIn)
        if(!good){
            alert("You must complete all required fields for all students")
        }
        return good
    })
})

Answer (score 0):

Couple problems in your code.

Use `$('student').eq(0)` instead of `$($('.student').get(0))`

You're getting the dom element from a jquery object and rewrapping it into a jquery object. The `eq(index)` function returns a jquery wrapped element.

You're trying to get a `val` property from `attr("name")`, which returns a string. You'll get undefined.

```
if ($(this).attr("name").val == 'name'){
   $(this).prop("readonly", true);
}
```

If you're trying to find the existence of the name attribute, just do

```
if ($(this).attr("name")){
   $(this).prop("readonly", true);
}
```

Lastly, you don't need to rewrap a jquery object with a jquery object.

```
$($('.student').last())
```

Jquery functions return the jquery object, meaning you can chain calls, and you don't need to rewrap it.

```
$('.student').last()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as below. Assuming your table has class `student` here is a working demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/L8tf3o8L/).

```
$(function(){
    var addStudent = function(data){
        var studentEl = $('.student tr:first').clone();
        studentEl.find('input').each(function(){
            var field = $(this).attr('name').replace('[]','');
            if (field === 'name'){
                $(this).prop("readonly", true);
            }
            $(this).val(data[field] || '')
        })
        if(data.client_no !== ''){
            studentEl.find('.will_update').text("Will update student information for "+data.name+'')
        }
        $('.student').last().after(studentEl)
    }
});
```